# How to fully exit Android application in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, exit

The application successfully exists, but it still stays in the background as active app? How to fully exit?

This is my code:

```
function showExitDialog() {
navigator.notification.confirm(
    ("Do you want to Exit?"), // message
    alertexit, // callback
    'Exit the application?', // title
    'YES,NO' // buttonName
);
}


function alertexit(button){

     if(button=="1" || button==1 && navigator.app) {
         navigator.app.exitApp();
     } else if(button=="1" || button==1 && navigator.device) {
         navigator.device.exitApp();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the `app.java` file in `cordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/app.java` in that file you will find method called `public void exitApp()` change that method as following

```
public void exitApp() {

        this.webView.postMessage("exit", null);
        finish();  
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, mate. But what if I build it online with phonegap builder?

Comment: it will buid you don't get any error as of my knowledge